# How to use LRU caching on disk with klepto?

Tags: klepto

I am trying to use klepto to do LRU caching. I would like to store the cache to disk, and am currently using klepto's `dir_archive` option for this. I have written the following code, largely based on the code in the klepto test scripts:

```
def mymap(data):
    return hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest()

class MyLRUCache:
    @lru_cache(cache=dir_archive(cached=False), keymap=mymap, ignore='self', maxsize=5)
    def __call__(self, data)
        return data

    call = __call__

    def store(self, data):
        self.call(data)

    # I would also appreciate a better way to do this, if possible.
    def lookup(self, key):
        return self.call.__cache__()[key]
```

This code appears to work fine until the cache reaches `maxsize`. At that point, instead of using LRU to remove a single item, `lru_cache` purges the entire cache! Below is the piece of klepto source code that does this (https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/safe.py):

```
# purge cache
if _len(cache) > maxsize:
    if cache.archived():
        cache.dump()
        cache.clear() 
        queue.clear()
        refcount.clear()
     else: # purge least recently used cache entry
        key = queue_popleft()
        refcount[key] -= 1
        while refcount[key]:
            key = queue_popleft()
            refcount[key] -= 1
        del cache[key], refcount[key]
```

So my question is, why does klepto purge "archived" caches? Is it possible to use `lru_cache` and `dir_archive` together?

Also, if my code looks completely nuts, I would really appreciate some sample code of how I **should** be writing this, since there was not much documentation for klepto.

ADDITIONAL NOTES:
I also tried defining `dir_archive` with `cached=True`. The in-memory cache still gets purged when `maxsize` is reached, but the contents of the cache are dumped to the archived cache at that point. I have several problems with  this:

1. The in-memory cache is only accurate until `maxsize` is reached, at which point it is wiped.
2. The archived cache is not affected by `maxsize`. Every time `maxsize` is reached by the in-memory cache, all items in the in-memory cache are dumped to the archived cache, regardless of how many are already there.
3. LRU caching seems impossible based on points 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi, I'm the package author.  Hmm… that's weird.  I'll play with it  a bit and see if I can make the purge behavior more configurable.  I'll add this as a ticket, if you don't.

Comment: So the intent was that if you pick a cache that is archived, the cache dumps to the archive and then clears when it hits `maxsize`.  If you have a cache that is not archived, it uses the LRU strategy to purge cached items (i.e. deletes and doesn't save them anywhere).  You seem to want a third option, which is when the cache hits `maxsize` it dumps via the LRU strategy to the archive.  The reason that is not done currently is that if the process is blocking, it can significantly slow a calculation (compared to the existing methods).  However, I will add it as an option.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you couldn't before your question, but now you can.
If you get the most recent `klepto` from github, and provide the new flag
`purge=False` -- then you get the behavior you are looking for.  I just added this in response to your question.

In your case:

`lru_cache(cache=dir_archive(cached=False), keymap=mymap, ignore='self', maxsize=5, purge=False)`

Or, for example:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=3, cache=dict_archive('test'), purge=True)
def identity(x):
  return x

identity(1)
identity(2)
identity(3)
ic = identity.__cache__()
assert len(ic.keys()) == 3
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 0
identity(4)
assert len(ic.keys()) == 0
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 4
identity(5)
assert len(ic.keys()) == 1
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 4

@lru_cache(maxsize=3, cache=dict_archive('test'), purge=False)
def inverse(x):
  return -x

inverse(1)
inverse(2)
inverse(3)
ic = inverse.__cache__()
assert len(ic.keys()) == 3
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 0
inverse(4)
assert len(ic.keys()) == 3
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 1
inverse(5)
assert len(ic.keys()) == 3
assert len(ic.archive.keys()) == 2
```

Please add a ticket if this doesn't do what you were expecting.  Thanks for the suggestion.