# Time-expiring cache in klepto

Tags: python, caching, klepto

I'm experimenting with [klepto](https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto) (v. 0.1.5.2) to cache some very heavy and time-consuming computations. In particular, I'm using `lru_cache` as decorator, coupled with a `hdfdir_archive` cache archive.

I managed to persist cache content on disk using the `purge=False` option in `lru_cache` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081207/how-to-use-lru-caching-on-disk-with-klepto), and it works like a charm. Anyway, I'd recompute the functions once in a while (even with the same input parameters), because some computations are based on data that could change after a certain period of time.

As simple workaround, I thought that the current date could be included in the input parameters of the functions, implementing a custom [keymap](http://klepto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/klepto.html#module-klepto.keymaps) that checks if the old entry has expired; but I have not found examples of how customize keymaps, so I have no idea if this solution is feasible or could work.

However, I'm wondering if a more elegant or simpler solution is already available in `klepto`. In other words, is there an option or policy to automatically invalidate cache entries after a preset period of time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `klepto`.  There is no cache in `klepto` that has time-expiring entries, however, it is on the TODO list.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply! I really appreciate `klepto`: it's a very interesting tool. Do you think that customizing the keymaps could be a possible solution for now? Can you point me out some resources or docs to learn how to customize and use keymaps?

Comment: Yes... you can customize the `keymaps`... but what you are looking to do is actually to create a custom archive with a time-expiring cache... that would be done by building a custom `cache`.  See `https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/_cache.py`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try.